# Как правильно перезаполнить tab состоящиe из ListFragment заданные LoaderManagerom?

Tags: android

Всем привет. Есть FragmentActivity, заполненная tabами c ListFragment .которые заполняются через LoaderManager. при смене табов криво обновляется содержимое. Допустим у меня есть два таба Tab1 Tab2 . когда я кликаю по Tab1 вся информация отображиается верно. потом кликаю Tab2 тоже все нормально. потом опять Tab1 и тут вылазит либо просто пустое пространство либо заполненное неверное информацией(если tab был пуст). посмотрел через debug отличие первого от второго клика на Tab1 в том что в первом случае в переменных приходят this и savedInstanceState =null, а во втором приходит Loder c данными . Пытался убить Loader в onDestroy taba `lm.destroyLoader(this.getTag().toString().hashCode())`, но тогда каждый непустой tab при пересоздании просто дает ошибку. так же для каждого tab создается Loader c собственным ID `lm.initLoader(this.getTag().toString().hashCode(), null, mCallbacks);`